# How to having two caches(redis backend) with different expire time in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cache, spring-data-redis

In my spring boot(1.2.6) application, I need different expire policies for different objects. The cache backend is redis.

What's the best practice to archive it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turned it out, currently it works now.

Originally I created different cache with different expire time, however it does not work. Looks like spring redis cache does not use the expire time specified in cache instance.

**Not working**

```
@Bean
public Cache cacheObjectName(StringRedisTemplate template) {
    return new RedisCache(CACHE_OBJNAME, CACHE_OBJNAME.getBytes(), template, 10 * 24 * 60 * 60);
}
```

Finally I had to create different cache manager with different expire time,

**Working implementation**

```
@Bean(name = MANAGER_NAME_1D)
public CacheManager cacheManager1D(StringRedisTemplate redisTemplate) throws Exception {
    final RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate(factory), Arrays.asList(CACHE_A, CACHE_B));
    redisCacheManager.setUsePrefix(true);
    redisCacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(60 * 60 * 24);
    return redisCacheManager;
}
```